# Existence of limit for a constant function except in a point, for peculiar limit definition

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a constant function ($f=0$), except at $x=a$ ($f=1$).

The definition of limit I'm using is the following:

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=b$
>
> iff
>
> $a$ is limit point of the domain of $f$ and
>   $\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}\forall_x(x\in D \land
>  |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-b|<\epsilon)$, where $D$ is the domain of $f$

Using this definition, am I correct in saying that there's no limit at $x=a$ for $f$ defined at the top? Because $x=a$ will always be in $D$ and with$
|x-a|<\delta$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the definition is incorrect: you need $x \in D$, $|x-a|<\delta$, as well as $|x-a|>0$. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement). So in particular the limit still exists at $x=a$.

Comment: @angryavian I know that definition, but the one I'm using here, it's also used in a textbook I'm reading...

Comment: what do you mean by $> |x - a|$ in your definition?

Comment: It also appears that your textbook assumes calculus to be a game of shunting symbols like $\forall, \exists, \epsilon, \delta$. Sorry it is game based on symbols like $<, >, +, -, \times, /$ with far more emphasis on $<, >$ compared to $+,-,\times, /$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it was just an automatic editing mistake by the editor of this site(MathJax? you can check it by observing the last 2 changes of the editing history of this post. ). Is it clearer now?

Comment: do you mean $\cap$ and not $\wedge$

Comment: @Bey I could write $x \in D \cap B_{\delta}(a)$ or  ($x \in D$ and $|x-a|<\delta$) they're equivalent propositions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I've just edited out a typo. Could you check if it's clearer now?

Comment: Your edit is OK, but as mentioned by @angryavian you must also include $0 < |x - a|$ in your definition. It is absolutely necessary to point out that the limit of $f$ at $a$ is totally independent of value of $f$ at $a$ (i.e. $f(a)$) and fully dependent on values of $f$ near $a$. By the way for your function $f$ in question the limit of $f$ at $a$ exists and the limit is $0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was assuming the $\wedge$ was associating with the $D$, not serving as a conjunction. Makes sense now.